# how to get the image names from html using php

Tags: php

php for get all image tags using

```
$html='<a herf="http://www.google.com">test</a></br>
       <p><img src="./../../src/image1.png"/></p>
       <a href="example.mpeg" title="Download movie">film name</a>
       <img border="0" src="/images/image1.jpg" alt="Image" />
       <img border="0" src="/images/image2.jpg" alt="Image"/>
       <img border="0" src="/images/image3.jpg" />';

preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$html, $imageTags);  
$string=join(PHP_EOL,$imageTags[0]);
// echo '<xmp>'. $string .'</xmp>';
```

after that how to get image names from this images tags?
like, image1.jpg

Comment: You can use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ to parse and process.

Comment: but i want get image names only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this,

```
$html='<a herf="http://www.google.com">test</a></br>
   <p><img src="./../../src/image1.png"/></p>
   <a href="example.mpeg" title="Download movie">film name</a>
   <img border="0" src="/images/image1.jpg" alt="Image" />
   <img border="0" src="/images/image2.jpg" alt="Image"/>
   <img border="0" src="/images/image3.jpg" />';


preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $html, $src);                
$srcArray = array_pop($src);

foreach($srcArray as $src ){
    $imgName=explode('/',$src); 
    $fileName[]=end($imgName);      
}
print_r($fileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

## Modified input

```
$html='<a herf="http://www.google.com">test</a></br>
<p><img src="./../../src/image1.png"/></p>
<a href="example.mpeg" title="Download movie">film name</a>
<img border="0" src="image1.jpg" alt="Image" />
<img border="0" src=image2.jpg alt="Image"/>
<img border="0" src=\'/images/image3.jpg\' />';
```

## If you want the image names only

```
preg_match_all('#([^/\'"=]*?[.](?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png))\b#i',$html, $imageTags);
print_r($imageTags);
```

## Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => image1.png
            [1] => image1.jpg
            [2] => image2.jpg
            [3] => image3.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => image1.png
            [1] => image1.jpg
            [2] => image2.jpg
            [3] => image3.jpg
        )

)
```

## Explanation

- Use `#...#` instead of `/.../` so you can use `/` without escaping it with backslash `\`.
- The opposite of `[/]` is `[^/]`. The last one means: Take every char except of `/`. So you can add more chars: `[^/\'"=]` - Those will not be taken.

  - The question mark `?` after asterisk `*` means: Don't be too greedy and take only a few chars as possible until you hit the full stop: `[.]`
- `(?:...)` means: Don't put that parenthesis result in output.
- `\b` (after .jpg) means: This is a **b**oundary: So the "word" is over = no normal text character follows.

## Remember

Parsing XML or HTML with RegEx is hacky.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add `/` in your regex:

```
$html='<a herf="http://www.google.com">test</a></br>
       <p><img src="./../../src/image1.png"/></p>
       <a href="example.mpeg" title="Download movie">film name</a>
       <img border="0" src="/images/image1.jpg" alt="Image" />
       <img border="0" src="/images/image2.jpg" alt="Image"/>
       <img border="0" src="/images/image3.jpg" />';

preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+\/?>/i',$html, $imageTags);  
$string=join(PHP_EOL,$imageTags[0]);
```

https://regex101.com/r/YjFzB4/1